# Executing linux command with "|" and "'\n'" in Python

Tags: python, linux

I try to execute linux command in Python, but I don't get any output and any error.

```
import subprocess, os
cmd = ["iwconfig", "wlan0", "|", "grep", "ESSID", "|", "awk", "-F:", "'{print $2}'", "|", "sed", "'s/\"//g'"]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate()
print(output.decode("ascii"))
```

The output should be the ESSID of connected Wi-Fi.

I am sorry, I read the other questions, but I can't get it.

Answer (score 2):

`|` is a shell feature. You need `shell=True`.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: It is weird, I get different output unlike with terminal.

Comment: If you are using `shell=True`, you may want to join the elements of `cmd` into a single string again, rather than letting `Popen` join them.

Comment: I am sorry, I read the other questions, but I can't get it.